# How to use picture-in-picture for amazon instant video?

Tags: safari, macos, picture-in-picture

On Youtube in safari, you can right click twice to get the PIP option.

However, I can't figure it out for amazon instant video

Comment: Does Amazon support PIP in Safari?  I've never seen any options to use it.  Do you have any info from Amazon that this is supported?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have access to Amazon Video, so I can't test this, but try out [PiPifier (Mac App Store link)](https://itunes.apple.com/app/pipifier-pip-for-nearly-every/id1160374471?mt=12). It installs a Safari extension that takes any HTML 5 video and puts it in a PiP window. You can [read more about PiPifier on GitHub](https://github.com/arnoappenzeller/PiPifier).